# Punctuations inside quote with regard to single quotation marks

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, quotation-marks

My friend told me about the party. "We had a lot of fun there. Jen was having a great time and kept yelling 'This is so much fun!' before passing out.

My friend told me about the party. "We had a lot of fun there. Jen was having a great time and kept yelling 'This is so much fun,' before passing out.

Should the single quote end with an exclamation mark or a comma?

Comment: The double quote after *out* is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Punctuate as normal. The punctuation is meaningful, to mark a sentence or phrase as an exclamation, that is one that expresses a strong or forceful emotion, such as anger, surprise, or joy.

From the context, it looks like Jen is expressing strong joy, so an exclamation mark at the end of her sentence is a good choice.